# HTML href - Hover not systematic

Tags: html, hover, href

I have observed a strange behavior with html href attribute :

Some of my links are note colored when cursor is hover, despite of a CSS selector defined for this.

When I insert an http link, my browser preview in the left bottom (Mozilla Firefox) is every time in https.

I know it seems weird and a very basic question, but I've never notided a behavior like this. Something I missed ?

Here is a demo

```css
dt{font-family:'Muli',sans-serif;font-size:14px;}
A:link {color: #1c1c1c;text-decoration:none;}
A:hover {color: #3d62e7;}
A:visited {color: #1c1c1c;text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli">

<DT>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<A target="_blank" HREF="http://www.discogs.com/fr/Eric-B-Rakim-Let-The-Rhythm-Hit-Em/master/13184">01 - Blue when hover, no problem</A>
<DT>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<A target="_blank" HREF="http://www.discogs.com/fr/Eric-B-Rakim-Dont-Sweat-The-Technique/master/13419">02 - No specific color when hover</A>
<DT>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<A target="_blank" HREF="http://www.discogs.com/fr/A-Tribe-Called-Quest-Midnight-Marauders/master/45947">03 - No specific color when hover</A>
<DT>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<A target="_blank" HREF="http://www.discogs.com/fr/A-Tribe-Called-Quest-We-Got-It-From-Here-Thank-You-4-Your-Service/master/1092073">04 - Blue when hover, no problem</A>
```

Comment: CSS rules and their order matters. Your `hover` should be after the rest of them, or else they will override it. In this case, move `hover` last.

Comment: The dupe link answer explains this further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your style for visited links:

```
A:visited {color: #1c1c1c;text-decoration:none;}
```

I would be willing to bet the ones you are not seeing change color are links you have already visited.

I can confirm this behavior (in Chrome). Once I visit one of the links in your example, it no longer reacts with the `hover` style.

The order in which you declare the rules matters. You can make the `:hover` state take precedence by altering the order of the rules and putting `:hover` after `:visited`:

```
A:link {color: #1c1c1c;text-decoration:none;}
A:visited {color: #1c1c1c;text-decoration:none;}
A:hover {color: #3d62e7;}
```

Comment: You're right, How could I miss this ? It suggest me another question: How to make the links visited remain black but be blue on hover?

Comment: Great, I doesn't know this rule, thank you. I've also noticed that when I place the hover after the underline, it also works fine. Thanks a lot for this obvious mistake of me.